No me guarda correctamente mis datos en .txt
Tengo un problema, cuando yo hago node tp1.js funciona bien siempre en la primera llamada, es decir, lee los datos, modifica y "guarda correctamente". Pero si yo ahora con los nuevos datos hago node tp1.js otra vez (es decir, vuelvo a ejecutar mi programa para repetir el proceso) no me lee los datos, me dice constantemente "undefined".
Me dice este error
**    salary: facturación.trim()
^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'trim')
at agregarInquilino (C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Gestion de datos\TPS\tp1\tp1.js:64:25)
at C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Gestion de datos\TPS\tp1\tp1.js:47:5
at Array.forEach ()
at cargarInquilinos (C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Gestion de datos\TPS\tp1\tp1.js:44:9)
at async main (C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Gestion de datos\TPS\tp1\tp1.js:80:3)
Node.js v20.12.2**
pero claro, en el primer llamado no tiene ese problema, no entiendo el por que. Y en el primer usuario me sale en consola "CAPOBIANCO GABRIELA FERNANDA 1.001 BIJOUTERIE Y MARROQUINERÍA 65000 undefined undefined undefined undefined" es como que al guardar los datos queda agregado caracteres undefined que no existirian por cada linea. Lo que menos entiendo es que esto es impreso en "agregarinquilino" y yo solo paso 5 argumentos y esto imprime mas de 10 jajaja
function agregarInquilino(nombre, apellido, id, rubro, facturación){
  console.log(nombre, apellido, id, rubro, facturación)
  const newUser = {
    name: nombre, 
    lastName: apellido, 
    id: id, 
    category: rubro, 
    salary: facturación.trim()
  }
  listaInquilinos.push(newUser);
}

CODIGO COMPLETO
const fs = require('fs'); // Cambia import fs from 'node:fs' por require('fs')
const stats = fs.statSync('./galeriaTP1.txt');

console.log(
  `
  Informacion archivo de texto - galeriaTP1.txt
    --> Es fichero?:  + ${stats.isFile()}
    --> Es directorio?:  + ${stats.isDirectory()}
    --> Es enlace simbolico?:  + ${stats.isSymbolicLink()}
    --> Tamaño en bytes?:  + ${stats.size}
  `
);

const readFile = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile('./galeriaTP1.txt', 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
      if(err) reject(err);
      else resolve(data);
    });
  });
}

const writeFile = (data) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.writeFile('./galeriaTP1.txt', data, 'utf-8', (err) => {
      if(err) reject(err);
      else resolve();
    });
  });
}


var listaInquilinos = [];

async function guardar(){
  const updatedData = listaInquilinos.map(user => `${user.name} ${user.lastName} ${user.id} ${user.category} ${user.salary}`).join('\n');
  await writeFile(updatedData);
}

async function cargarInquilinos(){
  const data = await readFile();
  const lines = data.split('\n');
  
  lines.forEach(line => {
    const charUser = line.split(/\t{1,}/);
    const [name, lastName, id, category, salary] = charUser;
    agregarInquilino(name, lastName, id, category, salary);
  });
}

function totalFacturacion(){
  let value = listaInquilinos
  .map(user => parseInt(user.salary) )
  .reduce( (acum, valor) => acum + valor );
  console.log(value);
}

function agregarInquilino(nombre, apellido, id, rubro, facturación){
  const newUser = {
    name: nombre, 
    lastName: apellido, 
    id: id, 
    category: rubro, 
    salary: facturación.trim()
  }
  listaInquilinos.push(newUser);
}

function modificarInquilino(id, nombre) {
  listaInquilinos = listaInquilinos.map(user => {
    if (user.id === id) {
      return { ...user, name: nombre };
    }
    return user;
  });
  console.log(listaInquilinos);
}

async function main(){
  await cargarInquilinos();
  totalFacturacion();
  agregarInquilino('ROBIN LELEU', 'MARÍA ELINA', '1.007', 'MANUALIDADES EN ALPACA Y CUERO-RESINA', '0');
  modificarInquilino('1.006', 'MANCEBO');

  await guardar();
  const data = await readFile();
  console.log(data);
}

main();



primero varible con acento no se usa en programacion ni  ´tildes´ ni ´ñ´ el ultimo valor enviado parese ser un entero ya que es salary y los enteros no tienen metodo trim() solo los string

Con respecto a:

es como que al guardar los datos queda agregado caracteres undefined que no existirian por cada linea

Los undefined no tienen nada que ver con eso.
Al leer una línea, vos haces line.split(/\t{1,}/), cuando en realidad los datos los estás separando con espacios y el error es por esto.
Al no haber tabs (\t) separando los datos, vas a obtener un arreglo con una posición (con todos los datos).
¿Que pasa si intentas recuperar datos de un arreglo en una posición que no está definida?
Obtenes undefined
Demo:


const line = `user.name user.lastName user.id user.category user.salary`;
const charUser = line.split(/\t{1,}/);
const [name, lastName, id, category, salary] = charUser;
console.log(charUser); // Arreglo
console.log(charUser[0], '===', name); // Posición definida
console.log(charUser[1], '===', lastName); // Posición no definida



Solución:
Tenes que separar los datos con tabs (\t), es decir, cambiar esta línea
const updatedData = listaInquilinos.map(user => `${user.name} ${user.lastName} ${user.id} ${user.category} ${user.salary}`).join('\n');

Por esto:
const updatedData = listaInquilinos.map(user => `${user.name}\t${user.lastName}\t${user.id}\t${user.category}\t${user.salary}`).join('\n');

Demo:


const listaInquilinos = [{
  name: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe',
  id: '1',
  category: 'Category',
  salary: '5000',
}]

// Al guardar los datos
const data = listaInquilinos.map(user => `${user.name}\t${user.lastName}\t${user.id}\t${user.category}\t${user.salary}`).join('\n');

// Al leer los datos
const lines = data.split('\n');
lines.forEach(line => {
  const charUser = line.split(/\t{1,}/);
  const [name, lastName, id, category, salary] = charUser;
  console.log(charUser); // Arreglo completo
  console.log(name, lastName, id, category, salary); // Todos los datos definidos
});




Con respecto al error:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'trim')

Básicamente te está diciendo que undefined no posee en su prototipo la función trim, y dado que facturación es igual a undefined por eso se rompe.

Listo, quedo arreglado, muchas gracias!
